# SWF - Incremental mining

Tags: data-mining

I am new to this data mining. Can anyone please help me with an example for Sliding Window Filtering algorithm(SWF) for incremental mining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are pseudo-codes in this [paper](http://arbor.ee.ntu.edu.tw/~mschen/paperps/cikm414.pdf), Section 3.1 shows an example of incremental mining by this algorithm. However I can't find any projects or working source codes with this algorithm implemented.

Comment: I have found this research paper - but not sure how to solve a problem on this.